# 'GeoAPI' and 'IPoint' could not be found in ASP.NET Core 3.0

Tags: c#, .net-core-3.0, asp.net-core-3.0

When updating a project from ASP.NET Core 2.2 to ASP.NET Core 3.0 started getting the errors:

```
The type or namespace name 'GeoAPI' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?).  
The type or namespace name 'IPoint' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?
```

On my project I have the following:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup>
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="3.*" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="3.*" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.NetTopologySuite" Version="3.*" />
</ItemGroup>
```

I have been trying to find if there were some changes in GEO objects but can't find anything.

Does anyone has any idea how to solve this?

Comment: As the error explains, you're probably missing a `using` directive in your code. Post your code, including the `using` lines at the top of the file. Have you added `using using GeoAPI.Geometries; ` ?

Comment: Yes, I have "using GeoAPI.Geometries" and is where I get the error "The type or namespace name 'GeoAPI' could not be found"

Comment: May be you are missing `https://www.nuget.org/packages/GeoAPI.Core/` nuget  package.

Comment: You may have to add the GeoAPI package explicitly. EF Core returns a Geometry/Geography object, not the GeoAPI objects so it may not have any dependencies on the package

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing [`GeoAPI.Core`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/GeoAPI.Core/) nuget package. Please install this. Error should go way.

```
PM > Install-Package GeoAPI.Core -Version 1.7.5
```

Comment: Yes, that solved it ... In ASP.NET Core 2.2 was not necessary.

Comment: Wait, are you sure this is the way? Because now I get an error on another project: 'Coordinate' is an ambiguous reference between 'GeoAPI.Geometries.Coordinate' and 'NetTopologySuite.Geometries.Coordinate'. If this is the solution isn't strange to get this error?

Comment: @MiguelMoura Okay! Give me a check. Better include your code to the question please!

Comment: @MiguelMoura It is confirmed that `GeoAPI` and `IPoint` is only available in `GeoAPI.Geometries` namespace while `Coordinate` is available in both `NetTopologySuite.Geometries` and `GeoAPI.Geometries` namespaces. So in case of `GeoAPI` and `IPoint`, you have to use `GeoAPI.Geometries` and in case of  `Coordinate`, you can use either of them. Thank you.

Answer (score 11):

Just want to add information to this, some things I found out when updating to .net core 3.0:

It is not necessary to install GeoAPI.Core, you can make it work with some minor refactoring. These are the steps I took to upgrade:

1. Upgrade to .NET Core 3.0 and Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.NetTopologySuite to 3.0.0
2. Remove all using GeoAPI.Geometries
3. Switch all occurences of geometry interfaces (IGeometry, IPoint, ILineString etc) to their corresponding implementation (Geometry, Point, LineString). This applies for properties in the database-model too (it works).

Also see: [Upgrading to 2.0 from 1.x](https://github.com/NetTopologySuite/NetTopologySuite/wiki/Upgrading-to-2.0-from-1.x)

**NOTE:**
Currently (2019-11-22) there's a bug preventing you to save large geometries to sql server. There's an open issue here:
https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/18813

**NOTE 2:**
The above mentioned bug was fixed in .NET 5

Comment: Hey Johan. Could you explain what you meant by remove all using GeoApi.Geometries? How did you manage to create a Point object using GeoApi.

Comment: @PiotrStulinski All you need is: using NetTopologySuite.Geometries; The GeoApi.Geometries only holds the interfaces while NetTopologySuite.Geometries has the implementations. You don't need to handle the interfaces anymore, you can stick to the implementations.

To create a point you just use the implementations in NetTopologySuite.Geometries: 

new Point(x, y)/new Point(x, y, z)